# How to subset the same rows/ids repeatedly in r

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, subset, plyr

I have a huge data frame with matched case control subjects. The matching case:control is 1:3. I am trying to resample the case ids and then extract the corresponding controls.

So, I have a vector of ids where the ids can be repeated. I want to extract the data for cases and controls for each id of the vector. The case and the matching controls have same case_num. The %in% always takes the unique ids from the data. I have used llply to do it. It takes about 2.5 seconds. Is there any other efficient way?

I am including an simple example and my solution to the question.

In my case, the length of the id vector in 1921, the function has to extract the controls 1921 times. So if the time can be reduced even a second, it will be actually a lot while I will be repeating the whole process 1000 times. Thank you!

```
test_data=     

data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,4,4,5,6),value=c('g','e','r','j','a','b','c'))

test_data
id value
1  1     g
2  1     e
3  2     r
4  4     j
5  4     a
6  5     b
7  6     c



id_vec= c(1,4,1,5)

library(plyr)
newdata.list=llply(id_vec, function(x) test_data[test_data$id==x,])

## or if we make our data a data.table then
library(data.table)
test_data= data.table(test_data)

newdata.list=llply(id_vec, function(x) test_data[id==x])

library(dplyr)
newdata.frame= bind_rows(newdata.list) ### making it a dataframe
newdata.frame
    id value
1:  1     g
2:  1     e
3:  4     j
4:  4     a
5:  1     g
6:  1     e
7:  5     b
```

Comment: Pls post the data as text, not as an image. Use `dput(your_data)` and copy-paste the result.

Comment: did the edits, also added the codes after getting the comments.

Comment: Probably safest not to mix plyr + dplyr + data.table; better just to pick 1. Plyr has been essentially replaced by dplyr, so probably not that one.

Comment: Thanks, but llply is taking the longest time. I also tried lapply, the time difference is insignificant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First split your data frame into a list of dataframes for each id:

```
split_data = split(test_data, test_data$id)
```

My guess is you could stop here and work with this list that has each `id` separately, but only once. However, if you really need copies of the data for each repetition in `id_vec`, just use list indexing:

```
result = split_data[id_vec]
```

---

This is very wasteful if at the end you are recombining into a single data frame. It involves copying the entire data, when all is really needed is the row numbers. If I understand correctly, your example is poor because the case numbers are repeated in the data, whereas your example data has unique `id`s. Here is a way, with repeated `id`s in both the data and the `id_vec` to resample data without making data frame copies:

```
## new example data
test_data2 = data.frame(id=c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4), value=c('g','e','r','j','a','b'))
id_vec2 = c(3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1)

rows = lapply(id_vec2, FUN = function(x) which(test_data2$id == x))    
result = test_data2[unlist(rows), ]
result
#     id value
# 4    3     j
# 5    3     a
# 1    1     g
# 2    1     e
# 3    2     r
# 4.1  3     j
# 5.1  3     a
# 6    4     b
# 1.1  1     g
# 2.1  1     e
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine. You are right my example is not perfect. I will edit it. Thank you very much.